# MongoDB Aggregation: Add new documents in the pipeline result when not matched

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a pipeline similar to the following

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': {
        $in: [<array of ids>]
      }, 
      '$expr': {
        '$eq': [
          {
            '$dateToString': {
              'date': '$timestamp', 
              'format': '%G-%m-%d'
            }
          }, '2023-03-20'
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': '<somcollection>', 
      'localField': '_id', 
      'foreignField': '<foreignId>', 
      'as': 'related'
    }
  }
]
```

When there is a match, the lookup works fine. The issue is due to the `$timestamp` comparison, in some cases, I would get no documents from the match pipeline. So there is no lookup to do.

I would like to add a new pipeline in between `$match` and `$lookup` where it would map over the results from `$match` to see if there is a document within `[<array of ids>]` is present and if not add a document with default values and the `_id` so that `$lookup` can work with that document.

I looked into `$replaceRoot`, `$mergeObjects` and a few others but they only work when there are documents present

Currently, I had to perform two separate queries and merge the results in my code with default values, but is there any way to perform this in a single query?

Comment: Format `%G` makes only sense in combination with ISO week number `%V`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$facet`. And I would suggest to use `$gt` and `$lte` for performance reasons:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: { $in: [<array of ids>] } } },
   {
      $facet: {
         nomatches: [
            {
               $match: {
                  $or: [
                     { timestamp: { $lt: ISODate('2023-03-20T00:00:00Z') } },
                     { timestamp: { $gte: ISODate('2023-03-21T00:00:00Z') } }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         matches: [
            {
               $match: {
                  timestamp: {
                     $gt: ISODate('2023-03-20T00:00:00Z'),
                     $lte: ISODate('2023-03-20T23:59:59.999Z')
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      '$lookup': {
         'from': '<somcollection>',
         'localField': '_id',
         'foreignField': '<foreignId>',
         'as': 'related'
      }
   }
])
```

or

```
     nomatches: [
        {
           $match: {
              timestamp: {
                 $not: {
                    $gt: ISODate('2023-03-20T00:00:00Z'),
                    $lte: ISODate('2023-03-20T23:59:59.999Z')
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ],
```

Comment: I need to query the timestamp in the first $match itself. There are around 6M documents in the collection. Querying for all matches in $facet is unnecessary and would take a lot of time

Comment: Maybe, I can try to limit to 1 document in the all facet, each from the <array of ids> ?

Comment: @LalithMohan Please see my update, does this work better?